# Использование/передача одного BluetoothService в разных Activity приложения

Tags: java, activity, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

К примеру я сделал некий BluetoothService и инициализировал его, обнаружив нужное устройство и успешно подключившись к нему. После этого, мне нужно использовать мой BluetoothService в других Activity моего приложения, на которые можно будет перейти с помощью кнопок, после успешной инициализации BluetoothService. Как правильно получить доступ к методам моего BluetoothService из других Activity приложения? Насколько я знаю, статик вызовы не вариант, тем более это фу, также Extra отпадает из-за сложности объекта, в том числе и Parcelable объекты.

Моя задача в том, что с ардуино приходит информация, и в зависимости от неё, мне нужно поменять значение в соответствующем окне приложения, понятное дело если оно активно. В том числе мне нужно отправить

**UPD**
Моя задача состоит в том, что мне нужно принимать и отправлять некие данные на Arduino с помощью блютуза.
Сама Arduino снимает данные с аналоговых портов и преобразовывает их в данные(вольты, омы, сил тока и т.д.) и отправляет по блютузу.

В комментариях моё внимание обратили на BroadcastReciever, после изучения этого 
момента, на сколько я понял, моё приложение должно выглядеть так:

Есть главное Activity. Есть N Activity, каждое из которых соответствует конкретному прибору, для которого будет поступать данные.

В главном Activity я инициализирую свой сервис блютуза и ловлю в нём сообщение от ардуино, далее в зависимости от собственного протокола делаю broadcast данных и, если activity, которая отвечает за данный прибор активна и в ней зарегистрирован reciever, то я делаю обработку данных, вывод в textview и т.д. В конечном итоге я могу сделать reciever в главном классе и кидать на него сообщения(broadcast) из всех activity "приборов", чтобы с помощью него отправлять данные на ардуинку. Т.е. грубо говоря, всё общение между activity будет построено на broadcast. Я правильно понял концепцию или нет? Правильно ли я подобрал реализацию для данной задачи? Важно подметить, что отдельное activity для каждого прибора очень необходимо.

Comment: в чем у вас проблема? Вы не умеете слушать сообщения с помощью BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Нет, не умею, пойду почитаю.

Comment: @danilshik я дополнил вопрос, не могли бы вы ознакомиться с ним ещё раз?

Comment: вы можете в любом Activity/Fragment регистрировать BroadCastReceiver, а при выходе из него Unрегистрировать.
Вы можете отправлять команды через IntentFilter, а получать через слушать сообщений BroadCastReceiver. На самом деле общаться с Service можно разными способами

Comment: @danilshik спасибо за ответ. Я это и имел ввиду в UPD части вопроса. Как Вы считаете, это оптимальное решение моей задачи из вопроса?

Comment: @TheProrotype только вы имели ввиду ссылаться на mainActivity и там отправлять данные. Я же имел ввиду регистрировать и отписываться в каждом из Activity/Fragment.

Использование Service имеет быть, но почему тогда Socket не использовать?

Comment: Тут только вопрос, ваш ардуино сам отправляет рандомно сообщения, или по вашему запросу?)

Comment: @danilshik здесь я точно не могу сказать, по идее после установления успешного соединения, я могу "включить" сбор данных по нужному мне прибору c N периодом, чтобы более менее плавно видеть как меняется измеряемая величина. Т.е. при открытии activity прибора, я смогу включить его измерение(отправив команду на ардуино) и он сам будет периодически снимать данные и присылать их на обработку и вывод по блютузу. 
В MainActivity я имел ввиду сделать broadcast IntenFilter, который при поступлении данных будет разбирать их и сам направлять по каналу нужного прибора. Что вы имеете ввиду под Socket?

Comment: У меня как бы и так есть блютуз сокет, если вы об этом, где я могу принимать и отправлять данные. https://hastebin.com/acohalusef.java

Comment: Понятное дело, что все активити будут подписываться на broadcast в onCreate(вроде) и делать unregister где нужно

Comment: @danilshik Добрый вечер. Вы бы могли в последний раз ознакомиться с моими комментариями выше и дать ответ на них?